# Creating a subset of an array in solidity, but couldn't able to do it

Tags: arrays, blockchain, solidity

I have declared an array and using the function **subset(uint start, uint end)** I am trying to get the subset of that array. But Solidity throws an error "**The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.
Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance.**"

Here's my Code..

```
pragma solidity >=0.8.0 <0.8.17;

contract Array{
    uint256[] public numbers;
    uint public length;
    function addNumToArr(uint num)public 
    {
        numbers.push(num);
        length=numbers.length;
    } 
    //function to get the subset of an arry
    function subsets(uint start, uint end)public view returns(uint[] memory){
        uint[] memory arr;
        uint count=0;
        for(uint i=start;i<end;i++)
        {
            arr[count]=numbers[i];
            count++;
        }
        return arr;
    }
}
```

input:
numbers=[2,4,6,8,10,12]

Operation:
subset(1,4)

Expected output:
arr=[4,6,8]